# Cummulative Frequency Distribution of a Histogram Bin(s) Inserts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I wanted to ask if there is a way to plot the **time series of inserts to a histogram bin**(s).

The input is a large list with x and y values (integers). I can easily produce a histogram using `plt.hist()` with a number of bins, but I would like to see the inserts to say bin 0 over time (x values).

So in a plot i'll have an x-axis showing time, and a y-axis showing a count, with a cummulative line for each bin.

Thanks

Comment: May we have an example of the data (as text) and perhaps a drawing of what you’re after?

Comment: Data: x = [0,1,2.....,1048576], y = [1135534, 8348293423, 38944345 (total 1048576 elements)].
I could put y in a list and then plot it with various bins. So at the end you have a simple histogram with various bins. I would like to see the inserts into each bin over time.

Comment: Even the inserts from y to the bin with x as as the x axis on the line plot would work as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a visual.  Essentially, X is time, and Y is cumulative values, with a trace for each bin.  What is the bin width? ... or I’ll just derive a sample dataset for demonstration.

Comment: The bin width can be arbitrary.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing a key point ... wouldn't this just produce a graph with a single diagonal line, with (n) colours, (one for each trace)?  Presume there are three bins, therefore three traces. Each trace accumulates a count (incrementing by one) - so over time (X) all traces would overlay as all are incrementing by the same value.  What have I missed ... ?  Additionally, a histogram shows range (or sigma) on the xaxis, not time.  I presume what you are actually after is a time series (line) trend.

Comment: I was trying to get a line for each bin over time. So three bins would produce three lines. Each bin accumulates a count, they are not incrementing by the same value (histogram bins). Yes i'm after a time series line for each bin's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure my understanding of your problem is correct, but I tend to think that you want to visualize the insertion of values in given bins through time, as those values come in one by one.

```
In [1]: import numpy
   ...: import pandas
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Let's first create the example data set...
In [2]: lowest, highest = 0, 10
   ...: amount_of_samples = 100
   ...: samples = numpy.random.randint(lowest, highest+1, amount_of_samples)

# ...then make 6 bins...
In [3]: amount_of_bins = 6
   ...: bins = [
   ...:     (i*highest/amount_of_bins, (i+1)*highest/amount_of_bins)
   ...:     for i in range(amount_of_bins)
   ...: ]

# ...and, finally, assign each value to the appropriate bin.
In [4]: df = pandas.DataFrame(
   ...:     data=[
   ...:         [1 if (sample >= interval[0] and sample < interval[1]) else 0
   ...:          for interval in bins]
   ...:         for sample in samples],
   ...:     columns=[f'{bins[i][0]:.1f}-{bins[i][1]:.1f}' for i in range(6)],
   ...: )

# We need to account for the fact that the above command excludes
# the highest value from the bins
In [5]: last_bin_column = f'{bins[-1][0]:.1f}-{bins[-1][1]:.1f}'
   ...: df[last_bin_column] += (samples == highest)

# We then get a cumulative sum for each bin, through time
In [6]: df = df.cumsum()

In [7]: ax = df.plot()

In [8]: ax.set_xlabel('time')
Out[8]: Text(0.5, 0, 'time')

In [9]: plt.savefig('hist.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Result]

Comment: yeah that is the solution I wanted. Thanks.